# PHP: unserialize() doesn't return an array

Tags: php, serialization

I have this code below to insert serialized data in a field (order_pictures):

```
  $pictures_id = unserialize($category->getOrderPictures());
  array_push($pictures_id, $picture->getId());
  $category->setOrderPictures(serialize($pictures_id));
```

It works ok the first time I execute it. At least, it stores `b:0;` in the `order_pictures` field.

But when I execute it again, the value of `$pictures_id` is `bool(false)`, and I expected an array type.

Any idea?

Regards

Javi

Comment: `var_dump($pictures_id);` please

Comment: What it says `var_dump(unserialize($category->getOrderPictures()));`? It returns the `b:0;` or a long string?

Comment: var_dump($category->getOrderPictures()); please seriously, you're not giving us enough data to solve your problem.

Comment: `var_dump(unserialize($category->getOrderPictures()));` please. Especially interested in the long string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to `unserialize` the contents of `$category->getOrderPictures()` before it's ever been initialized, so `$pictures_id` is getting boolean `false` in it, which is the result of `unserialize` failing.  Then the `array_push()` is failing because `$pictures_id` isn't an array.

Try this:

```
$pictures_id = $category->getOrderPictures();
if($pictures_id)
    $pictures_id = unserialize($pictures_id);
else
    $pictures_id = array();
array_push($pictures_id, $picture->getId());
$category->setOrderPictures(serialize($pictures_id));
```

Answer (score 1):

> It works ok the first time I execute it. At least, it stores b:0;

And thats it: `b:0;` is not an array, but its its a boolean (`false`)

Unsing PHPs interactive mode (`php -a`)

```
php > var_dump(unserialize('b:0;'));
bool(false)
php > var_dump(serialize(false));
string(4) "b:0;"
```

This means, that the *serialization* probably gives you unexpected results, *before* you put it into the database. When reading from the database everything works fine, but the content is not, what you exptect.